# A Calculus Question from Math 1A Fall 2018 Practice 2

Tags: calculus

Two rockets are fired vertically into the air from the ground. The second rocket is launched four seconds after the first. The velocity of the first rocket is $v_1(t) = 6 − t$ metres per second and the velocity of the second is $v_2(t) = 10 − t$ metres per second,where $t$ is the time in seconds after the first launch.

How long after first the launch will both rockets be at the same height?

Below is my wrong solution (but I have no idea why it is wrong and that is my question QAQ)
$$
\text{Let $x$ be the time elapsed after the first launch.} 
\\ \text{Then} \int_0^x v_1(t)dt = \int_0^{x-4}v_2(t)dt 
\\ \implies   \int_0^x (6-t)dt = \int_0^{x-4}(10-t)dt 
\\ \implies (6t-\frac{1}{2}t^2)\Bigg |_0^x = (10t-\frac{1}{2}t^2)\Bigg | _0 ^{x-4}  \\
\implies 6x  = 10x -40 - 8 + 4x \implies x = 6
$$
However, the correct answer is $x=8$. Could anyone tell why the method I used is wrong?

[Here's the correct solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ2tC.png)

Comment: It is stated that the $t$ is the time after the first launch. Therefore your second integral should go from $4$ to $x$.

Answer (score 3):

> The velocity of the first rocket is $v_1(t) = 6 − t$ metres per second and the velocity of the second is $v_2(t) = 10 − t$ metres per second,where $t$ is the time in seconds *after the **first** launch*.

The time $t$ in the second velocity function is also counted as seconds *after the **first** launch* so in your integral, you should not start from $t=0$ (and end at $t=x-4$) but start at $t=4$ (and end at $t=x$), to get:
$$\int_0^x v_1(t) \,\mbox{d}t = \int_\color{red}{4}^\color{red}{x} v_2(t) \,\mbox{d}t \iff \int_0^x \left(6-t\right) \,\mbox{d}t = \int_\color{red}{4}^\color{red}{x} \left(10-t\right) \,\mbox{d}t \iff x = 8$$

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I got it :).

Comment: Alright, you're welcome!